# Solidity view returns an error of 'out of gas'

Tags: solidity

When running a public view function that I deployed to etherscan testnet, I get the following error:

> Returned error: out of gas

I have a forloop that loops 500 times which I assume is taking too long. Is there any ways counteract it taking a long time to process?

Comment: arrange your contract code so that you can make for loop in front end code

Comment: @Yilmaz not a bad idea but unfortunately it's the tokenURI function that opensea reads

Comment: I believe you should never ever implement for loop in solidity. You have 500 items but what if for a large app, app gets 500000 items. How are you gonna handle it? you should paste your contract so we can get an idea.

Comment: 500 is the max. I'm generating random svg's @Yilmaz